# Linq return all columns from all tables in the join

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have 2 tables both of them contain dynamic columns and I wish to retrieve a collection of datarow with all the columns from both the tables(later i will bind it to a grid view) after performing left outer join.

Sample Query:

```
var query = from TableA in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            join TableB in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() on new { col1 = TableA.Field<Int32>("colA"), col2 = TableA.Field<DateTime>("colB") }
            equals new { col1 = TableB.Field<Int32>("colA"), col2 = TableB.Field<DateTime>("colB") }
            into GJ
            from sub in GJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select TableA;
```

Problem:
I want to select tableA and tableB together. The above sample query works and it populates all columns of tableA after left outer join. But i wish to retrieve all the columns from both the tables. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select both parts into an anonymous type:

```
var query = from TableA in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            join TableB in [ ...] on [...] equals [...] into GJ
            from sub in GJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { RowA = TableA, RowB = sub };
```

Each element of the result will have two properties: `RowA` being a row from `TableA`, and `RowB` being a matching row from `TableB` *or* null if no rows from `TableB` matches `RowA`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Lets say these are the columns of Table A (ColumnA, columnB, ColumnC) and the columns of TableB (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnD, ColumnE). So i wish to extract a datarow collection with all columns (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE). A output very similar to select * from tableA left outer join Tableb on [..some join..] ... Can you elaborate on how i can achive it.

Comment: @Alex: Well you *could* flatten them out in the select clause... but why not just keep the two rows separately?

Comment: My reason: got lots of queries I'm adding joins to (which had none before), lots of AutoMapper maps, and not a lot of time :(.